Why doesn't my Android activity receive onResume() when canceling a BillingClient transaction after being backgrounded?
My Android app has one consumable transaction and it works fine in normal BillingClient purchase flow. But if the app is backgrounded while the Play Store purchase pop-up is displayed, when the app is resumed and the purchase is canceled, my activity doesn't receive an onResume() call.
Here's the sequence to reproduce:

Open app, choose to purchase item
Play Store purchase UI slides up from bottom of screen
Background the app
Foreground the app
My activity does not receive an onResume()
Cancel the purchase transaction by touching outside the purchasing UI dialog
My activity does not receive an onResume()

This is happening on Android 12, 13, and 14 devices. Why is this happening and is there anything I can do to fix it?
More information to help clarify:
My activity receives an onPause() and onDestroy() when backgrounding the app. But when the app is foregrounded I never receive onResume() or onStart() or onCreate().
So my app appears in the recents list but it never draws anything and to the user appears like the phone itself is unresponsive because my invisible app is swallowing all touch input.
Is there a way to close the purchasing UI when my app gets background, thus preventing the destruction of my activity?

I'm actively working on adding IAP to my app and have a purchase flow in place. I followed your steps on a device with Android 12 and my Activity's onResume is called as expected. You've shown no code so I have to assume you have a bug.

No code is necessary. I put a breakpoint in my onResume method and it never gets called when my app is foregrounded with the purchase UI open.

"when my app is foregrounded with the purchase UI open" - that is wholly expected since the purchase UI is its own activity and this is different than the steps you outlined in your question (crucially step 5 where you cancel the transaction). Put a breakpoint in onPause - it'll hit when you enter the billing flow.

Updated OP to clarify. Yes onPause() is called entering the billing flow. My issue is that onResume() is never called, even after billing flow is completed.

I followed your updated steps in my own flow and get onResume called as expected.
Again, it's fairly clear that you have a bug. You may not think sharing code is necessary but unless you show (not just roughly describe) what you're doing, this is a guessing game.
Maybe you have a weird set of launch flags on your activity. Maybe you typed "onResume" wrong. Maybe you didn't set a breakpoint correctly. Without your context, this is impossible to answer unless you can share a minimal reproducible sample.

So should I have phrased the question differently? I have a working app and onResume is called every other time one would expect it to be. There's no "bug" in my code because it's just an Activity's onResume. I have one, it gets called every other time, but not this time. The steps above aren't to reproduce, they're to show the sequence of events happening to me. So perhaps the question should be "What would prevent my activity's onResume from being called when the purchase UI is displayed and the app is backgrounded"?

"What would prevent my activity's onResume from being called when the purchase UI is displayed and the app is backgrounded"? - Nothing that I'm aware of. And, again, it works for me. Provide a link to a repo or zipped project that has a working, reproducible example of the issue. Otherwise, not sure what else to suggest. Good luck.

Based on this discussion I tried something that seems to have worked, although it may cause other problems internal to my app. My AndroidManifest.xml tagged the activity as "singleInstance", and removing that seems to have fixed the behavior.

These Activity lifecycle methods are always being called, without any exception.
And it should already have resumed, when being brought back into the foreground.
You might be barking up the wrong tree, as this is not how it is supposed to work;
better check for BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED instead.

I put a breakpoint in my onResume method and it never gets called when my app is foregrounded with the purchase UI open. I know that's not how it's supposed to work, it's not behaving as expected. USER_CANCELED isn't the issue. If you background the app while the purchasing UI is displayed, then foreground the app, onResume() is not called even if you don't cancel the transaction.
